# PHP array value replacement with recursive function inside a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I got a array called fruits. In this array if i have `oranges` I will change it to `I like` and after that any other oranges comes up change value with a recursive function.

So far I have come up with this =>

```
$fruits = array("apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "orange");

foreach($fruits as $key=>$fruit){

    if($fruit == "orange"){
        $fruits[$key] = "I like";
        $fruits = rec_fruits($fruits, 0);
    }

}

function rec_fruits($arr, $i){
    if(count($arr) > $i ) {
        if($arr[$i] == "orange" ){

            $arr[$i] = "grape";

        }

        $i++;
        return rec_fruits($arr, $i );
    } else {

        return $arr;
    }

}
```

This is not making any changes to the `$fruits` array. Even when I use the recursive function like this nothing is changed inside the `$fruits`=>

```
function rec_fruits(&$arr, $i)
```

Usage in the foreach without assigning it  to `$fruits` array =>

```
rec_fruits($fruits, 0);
```

I know there are ways to achieve this, but i wanted to do like this.

What i want in the array to finally like this =>

> Array (
>
> [0] => apple
>
> [1] => I like
>
> [2] => apple
>
> [3] => grape
>
> [4] => watermelon
>
> [5] => grape )

Comment: `$i++;` **return**  `rec_fruits($arr, $i );`

Comment: if https://eval.in/1057556 is not expected result, show in the question, what you want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have been wondering why the heck it doesn't make any changes to the `Array` then it's because of following lines:

```
$fruits = array("apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "orange");
// Note: Your above array is not an associative array which contains Key-Value pairs

// But here in the bellow foreach-loop you are trying to instantiate a Key-Value
// pair for each of the element in the given array
foreach($fruits as $key=>$fruit){
    // So it doesn't even touch following lines and it doesn't go for the recursive function call too :D
    if($fruit == "orange"){
        $fruits[$key] = "I like";
        $fruits = rec_fruits($fruits, 0);
    }
}
```

So what I did is for all the ease of pain, I replaced the foreach-loop with traditional old-school for-loop. Now the code looks as following and everybody are happy:

```
<?php

$fruits = array("apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "orange");

for($i = 0; count($fruits) > $i; $i++){
    if($fruits[$i] == "orange"){
        $fruits[$i] = "I like";
        $fruits = rec_fruits($fruits, 0);
    }
}

echo json_encode($fruits);

function rec_fruits($arr, $i){
    if(count($arr) > $i ) {
        if($arr[$i] == "orange" ){
            $arr[$i] = "grape";
        }

        $i++;
        return rec_fruits($arr, $i );
    } else {
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

The answer is as follows:

```
["apple","I like","apple","grape","watermelon","grape"]
```

Hope this was helpful to you!

Comment: And one thing, I didn't evaluate anything about your Recursive function, since I found the bug earlier code lines of your above script. Seems like it does what you exactly intended it to do for you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to accomplish. But when calling `rec_fruits` you are not returning anything when `count($arr) > $i`, therefor your are returning `null` to `fruits`, which then causes the notice of the undefined index.

```
function rec_fruits($arr, $i){
    if(count($arr) > $i ) {
        if($arr[$i] == "orange" ){

            $arr[$i] = "grape";

        }

        $i++;
        return rec_fruits($arr, $i );
    } else {

        return $arr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah! it fixed the error , but it still not give out the results i wanted. What ever the results from the function need to assign to the original array. I also updated the question

Answer (score 0):

A sample recursive approach

```
$array = array("apple", "orange", "pear", "orange", "apple", "orange", "orange");
$key = "orange";
$value = "I like it";

// array_search will return index of the value if it exists in mentioned source 
// empty actually check for a FALSE value.
while(!empty($index = array_search($key, $array))) { 
  $update = array($index => $value);     
  $array = array_replace($array, $update);
}

print_r($array); // all oranges are replaced with your
```

Comment: the thing is what I need to use a foreach and inside it a recursive function